# Why isn't the resume key working for enumitem package

Tags: enumitem

How can I make the `resume` key work when my `enumerate`d lists are contained within separate `multicol` environments?

Here's the code that's not working:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problem,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic{problemi}.},leftmargin=*,resume}
\def\remembered[#1]{\typeout{Call #1:\arabic{problemi}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Random content
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{problem}
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[First]

more content
\begin{multicols}{3}
\remembered[Inside 2nd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[Outside second]

more content
\begin{multicols}{3}
\remembered[Inside 3rd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[Outside 4th]

\end{document}
```

The `\remember` command seems to indicate that the value of the counters isn't being localized by the `multicols` environment.  So, why can't `resume` find the correct value to resume from?

Without the `multicols` environment everything works as desired:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problem,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic{problemi}.},leftmargin=*,resume}
\def\remembered{\typeout{\arabic{problemi}}\par I remember: \arabic{problemi}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Random content
\begin{problem}
\item something
\end{problem}
\remembered[First]

more content
\remembered[Inside 2nd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\remembered[Outside second]

more content
\remembered[Inside 3rd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\remembered[Outside 4th]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`resume` acts locally, so it won't survive a group like `multicols` or any other environment, for that matter. You need to use a `series` to keep the effect global:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{problem}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[problem,1]{label={\bfseries\arabic{problemi}.},leftmargin=*,resume=problem}
\def\remembered[#1]{\typeout{Call #1:\arabic{problemi}}}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

Random content
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{problem}
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[First]

more content
\begin{multicols}{3}
\remembered[Inside 2nd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[Outside second]

more content
\begin{multicols}{3}
\remembered[Inside 3rd]
\begin{problem}
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\item something
\end{problem}
\end{multicols}
\remembered[Outside 4th]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem wasn't one of remembering the counter, but one of remember which counter it is to restore?